# Global screen-span onclick to trigger an event javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, global

How would I specify that a click anywhere on the screen registers and triggers an event? I tried the `<body>` tag like so

```
<body onclick="skipFade();">
<script>
function skipFade() {
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger an event when you click anywhere on the screen

```
$(document).click(function(){

});
```

Bind an event on document instead of body , because **body** is a child of **document** , and the space occupied by the **body** may be smaller than the space occupied by the **document**

### UPDATE

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhH9V/3/)

Comment: @janicehoplin i have update the answer with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

**It seems your body doesn't have any content inside it!**
First create atleast a `div` inside it.

Then ,you need to use `$('body').on('click', function () ...` as follows,

### Page Body :

```
<body>
    <div>
      <%--Your page content here--%>
      <img src="http://www.etnforum.com/templates/thewei-zz3/images/etnDiamond2015.png" /><br /><br />
      Happy April Fool's Day!
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('body').on('click', function () {
        //do some code here i.e
        alert("ok");
        $('body').append('<br/>It is a body click AND<br />');
      });
      $(document).click(function(){
          $('body').append('It is a Document click<br />');
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

**JSFiddle :** [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/JhH9V/6/)

Comment: This doesn't work on the entire document , but only on the portion occupied by the body